# Django Modelchoicefield values in different format

Tags: django, model

I have created form with ModelChoiceField and loading the values from database model.
I am using below code for creating form

```
class MetamodForm(forms.Form):
     metamodule_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Metamodule.objects.all().values("name").distinct(),empty_label='Pick a Meta module')
```

But i am getting output format as

```
{'name': u'CCD infra'}
{'name': u'dependf'}
{'name': u'BAR weste'}
```

I am not sure why i am getting the above output. Please provide me a solution.

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: just the data what i have in database model. CCD infra ,  dependf, BAR weste

Comment: @crhodes: When i use Metamodule.objects.all() i get the correct output as expected. But when i use values('name') i am getting that kind of output.

Comment: .values() returns a ValuesQuerySet, which may behave differently than you might expect here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: @scoopseven: Okay. Is there any possibility to get the distinct objects without using values() or values_list()  ?

Comment: Why not just use Metamodule.objects.all() ? If you want distinct values, use distinct: Metamodule.objects.distinct(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: @scoopseven: I have used that and tried. Problem here is i have to get distinct of a particular field not the whole record. So even though i am using the distinct() i am getting the similar output

Answer (score 0):

In this example, since you're using .all(), you shouldn't need to use distinct.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Values returns something other than a QuerySet, ( a ValuesQuerySet ), which is why you're not getting the format you want.

The solution would be to simply not use the .values and .distinct calls on the queryset.

Replace

```
forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Metamodule.objects.all().values("name").distinct(),
    empty_label='Pick a Meta module')
```

With

```
forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Metamodule.objects.all(),
    empty_label='Pick a Meta module')
```

I'm guessing that you're trying to get the modelform to display the 'name' field as the choices.  You can either write Metamodule's unicode method to affect how it's displayed on the form, or use ModelChoiceField's label_from_instance.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

Answer (score 0):

On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply.

So if you're using PostgreSQL, you can do:

```
Metamodule.objects.distinct('name)
```

If not, here's a possible kludge. I'm sure someone will update this with a one-liner that does the same thing.

```
metamodules = Metamodule.objects.all()
metamodule_name_list = []
metamodule_id_list = []
for metamodule in metamodules:
    if metamodule.name not in metamodule_name_list:
        metamodule_name_list.append(metamodule.name)
        metamodule_id_list.append(metamodule.id)
distinct_metamodules_by_name = Metamodule.objects.filter(id__in=metamodule_id_list)

forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=distinct_metamodules_by_name,
    empty_label='Pick a Meta module')
```

I have no idea why you're doing this, but note that while you'll get a distinct "name" in your dropdown, 
you may not get the id/object you're actually looking for while processing in your view.